# Jooq native query doesn't use connection information

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb, jooq, testcontainers-junit5

Inside my integration test I configured my dslContext

```
    String connectionURL = mariaDBContainer.getJdbcUrl();
    String username = mariaDBContainer.getUsername();
    String pw = mariaDBContainer.getPassword();
    DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, username, pw), SQLDialect.MARIADB);
```

and wrote an insert:

```
        dslContext
            .insertInto(ATTACHMENT, ATTACHMENT.ID_ATTACHMENT)
            .values("abc", 999L)
            .execute();
```

which works pretty fine. No problem at all.

So, as I need to add a lot of data I don't want to populate my codebase as much. So I moved the inserts into a file and reading it inside my test:

```
        Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("src/test/resources/attachments.sql"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .forEach(queryValue -> dslContext.query(queryValue).execute());
```

This is pretty handy for me, because now I can copy paste the insert statements, which are generated by DBeaver, into a file and let jooq do the rest. The content of the sql file is:

```
INSERT INTO database.ATTACHMENT (ID_ATTACHMENT, ID_ATTACHMENT_DATA_REF)
VALUES('iuha99assU-eZ8ijZaHkUQ', 24719);
INSERT INTO database.ATTACHMENT (ID_ATTACHMENT, ID_ATTACHMENT_DATA_REF)
VALUES('iuha99assU-OPoias98s7', 27085);
....
```

BUT! A connection issue is thrown and I dont know why, because my dslContext is well configured as you can cleary see from the suceessfull executed dslContext.insertInto.. commands. The error:

> Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.MariaDbSqlException: INSERT command denied to user 'test'@'172.17.0.1' for table 'ATTACHMENT'
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.MariaDbSqlException.of(MariaDbSqlException.java:34)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.exceptionWithQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:194)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.exceptionWithQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:177)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:321)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.ClientSidePreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientSidePreparedStatement.java:220)
> ... 72 more
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: INSERT command denied to user 'test'@'172.17.0.1' for table 'ATTACHMENT'
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readErrorPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1694)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1556)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1519)
> at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:318)
> ... 73 more

Why does the dslContext has an seperate configuration for .query()? Or does I misunderstood something? I appreciate your opinion, thanks.

Comment: Well, what exact query did you try to execute from your SQL script? Is it really exactly the same? Or are you using different schemas? Different name cases?

Comment: Good question, I will add it to the descriptions, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, embarrassing for me, the solution is pretty simple:
I just removed the "database" from my sql script and it works.
Thanks Lukas Eder for pointing me to this direction.